# ASP.NET 3.5 Facebook iframe application Library or Samples that work? Specifically tagging photos

Tags: .net, facebook, iframe, photo, tagging

Brief version: I am looking for an example or a decent library that will run on .NET 3.5 for uploading and tagging images in an iframe web application for facebook

I have tried several libraries and code samples. I have brute-forced through various iterations and attempts at configuring various requests. I can achieve working versions of what I want to do in PHP as well as .NET 4.0 but unfortunately I need this to work in .NET 3.5

I have tried using a couple of development toolkits (one from MS and one that came as a VSI for Visual Studio) as well as just using the facebook.dll and facebookweb.dll with raw code. My closest iteration involved me being able to create an album and upload photos to it but I am unable to tag because Facebook expects a certain ID and this ID causes the older dll's to crash.

I can go into specifics but I have over a dozen projects each with a small stumbling block somewhere (one won't list photos in the albums, one won't produce an authkey that Facebook will accept for tagging, etc). I have tried straight graph requests, but when I take a working url from Facebook's generator it fails from my code (though it works in the .NET 4.0version)

I am tearing my hair out. Does anyone have any tips, or information - does this even work with any 3.5 libraries? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the Facebook Graph Toolkit http://computerbeacon.net/ has a .NET 3.5 compilation availble, which has been my saviour.